# How to make connection between two different smart contract address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, ether, remix

**e.g. "ABC" contract will use "XYZ" properties and methods 
Both contract owner is same.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in Remix:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract XYZ {
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function doSomething() external {
        emit SomethingDone(address(this));
    }

    event SomethingDone(address _addr);
}

contract ABC {
    address public owner;

    XYZ xyz_;

    constructor(XYZ _xyz) public {
        xyz_ = _xyz;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function interactWithXYZ() external {
        xyz_.doSomething();
    }
}
```

First, deploy contract `XYZ`. Then, deploy contract `ABC` using the address of the deployed `XYZ` contract. When that's done, try calling `ABC` 's `interactWithXYZ()` method. You'll see an event in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an interface with all the methods of your contract XYZ

```
interface IXYZ {
function doSomething() external;
```

}

and then you call it inside your contract where you want to use it with the address contract

```
IXYZ(xyz_).doSomething();
```